# Web Application best practice: ephemeral session or expiring sessions?

Tags: user-expectation, web-app, login

While working on an application using Node.js and Express, I was finding an interesting and perplexing issue in my UX testing. The application had session settings for "maxAge: 24 hours" and "ephemeral: true" - however I was finding that neither held to be true, my session appeared to always be available unless I actually logged out.

A little research confirmed that, at least with express-session, these 2 settings do not work together. Some deeper research turns up that in the UX world, ephemeral and expiring sessions are like oil and water, eg: what's the purpose of having a session that expires if you're going to kill it when the browser closes and vice-versa.  I've been told that it would be a confusing UX to do both.

Now I'm trying to determine what would actually be the best user experience? I realize this may be application dependent. My application is a simple database management interface. Users login, can manage tables in a database and that's it.

Should I put a maxAge on the session and expire them for idle activity, or expire the session only when the browser closes? I suppose a short age expiration after a period of time, ALSO covers the browser being closed.  On the other hand, a user may go inactive for a period of time, while leaving the browser open, with the intent of returning to it.  What scenario provides the best end-user UX that would be the least confusing?

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would consider flipping your question, as it's less about UX and more about what is the appropriate consideration for the security of the application. It will depend on the sensitivity of the data held within your app.

If it's within the acceptable boundaries of the system too persist application sessions for a given period of time (in your case 24 hours) then it's always going to be more preferential for users to not have to constantly login repeatedly every time they re-open their browser.

In this situation though - as much as this is UX biased domain to be garnering opinion - security of your application is almost more of an important factor for consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the Bad Actors and their Use-Cases for your application:

User logs in at a hotel web kiosk, does some stuff, forgets to logout and doesn't close the browser. Bad Actor can come along and continue that session. This is essentially why sessions and timeouts exist.

Poorly implemented, session expiry is applied exactly the same way everywhere - even if you are accessing the system from the same computer and same IP address as you have every other day.